# SASS: How to apply '&' to selector?

Tags: sass

For example, I described some class:

```
.class1 {
  .class2 {
    .class3 {
      // some CSS properties
    }
  }
}
```

and here is an example of DOM structure:

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
          <span class="class3">1</span>
          <span class="class3">2</span>
          <a class="class3">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to apply specific styles for a.class3.
Something like:

```
.class1 {
  .class2 {
    .class3 {
      // some CSS properties

      a.& {
        // custom CSS properties for a.class3 within the .class2 within the .class1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible here.

The & basically gets replaced by the CSS path up to that point (here: `.class1 .class2 .class3`). So, in your example, you'd get

```
a..class1 .class2 .class3
```

This of course make no sense for several reasons.

Your problem is that you want to insert the `a` *inside* the CSS path.

```
.class1 .class2 A.class3
```

That's not possible.

The only way this could work would be by giving your `a` another class that can be appended to the path

```
.class1 {
  .class2 {
    .class3 {
      // some CSS properties

      &.myLink {
        // custom CSS properties for a.class3 within the .class2 within the .class1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then the path would be expanded to `.class1 .class2 .class3.myLink`

Comment: Yea, thank you very much for your answer. Currently I solved the problem in the same way as you showed. I just wanted to be sure that there is no another way to do it via '&'

Comment: Well.. Almost in the same way. I preffer to insert the a.class3 selector inside the .class2 selector. So there will be 2 selectors within the .class2: .class3 with general styles and a.class3 with specific styles.

Comment: "Well.. Almost in the same way. I preffer to insert the a.class3 selector inside the .class2 selector. So there will be 2 selectors within the .class2: .class3 with general styles and a.class3 with specific styles."

So you have a `& a.class3` as a sister to `.class3?` Interesting solution!